# Factoring Quadratic Formula Equation

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I have a Quadratic Equation that I input into the Quadratic Formula to solve for y.

$$2xy^{2}+8xy-z=0$$

$$y=\frac{-8x\pm \sqrt{(8x)^2 - 4(2x)(-z)}}{2(2x)}$$

I've been told factoring will take me to:

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{{z}}{2x}+4} -2$$

I'm not sure how they got from point A to point B.

Any help?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant I'm not sure how they got from the Quadratic Formula to the Result.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator and denominator have been divided by $4x$, which becomes $16x^2$ inside the square root. Since $4x$ *is* the denominator, it disappears and we are left with
$$y=-8x/4x\pm\sqrt{64x^2/16x^2+8xz/16x^2}=\sqrt{z/2x+4}-2$$
Clearly this only works if $x\ne0$.

Comment: Why did the sign change for 8xz?  Isn't -4(2x)(z) = -8xz?

Comment: @Zak You actually made a mistake, which I have edited in for you in the question.